# not working while trying to concatenate value of some string variable included from an external php file

Tags: php

I have a php file which goes like:

```
<?php

include('../../config.inc.php');

//some code
//some more code


$myVar = $config['A'].'some more string';

//even more code
?>
```

and the file config.inc.php looks something like this:

```
<?php
$config['A'] = 'abc';
$config['B'] = 'xyz';
?>
```

Is there any reason why the concatenation does not take place, and value of myVar becomes 'some more string' and not 'abcsome more string' ?

Comment: Verify if the included file is in the correct folder, and if it is readable

Comment: Yes, try `require()`.

Comment: Or better: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: What result do you get when you `echo var_dump($myVar);`?